# Filter and sum in Vega lite

Tags: sum, vega-lite

I am trying to plot a line graph using Vega-Lite (in Airtable) which plots cumulative sum of a field by date.
I want to filter out data points with empty dates.

I somehow need to combine the "valid" OP argument and the "sum" OP argument - OR add a filter. I can't just filter within airtable as a I have 3 different lines to overlay

```
    `  "transform": [
    {
      "sort": [{"field": "Latest plan date"}],
      "window": [{
          "op": "sum",
          "field": "Impact to baseline",
          "as": "planned_cumul"}
      ]
    }

    ],
  "layer": [
     {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "stroke": "maroon"
      },
      "encoding": 
        {
        "x": {

          "field": "Latest plan date",
          "type": "temporal",
          
          "title": ""
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "planned_cumul",
          "type": "quantitative"
             }
        }
     }
     ],
``'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out missing dates with a transform:

```
"transform": [
{"filter": "isValid(datum.date)"}
.....
```

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Two lines: one cumulated using window transform and totals, with blank dates filtered out.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2023-01-01", "total": 10},
      {"date": "2023-01-02", "total": 20},
      {"date": "", "total": 30},
      {"date": "2023-01-04", "total": 40},
      {"date": "2023-01-05", "total": 50},
      {"date": "", "total": 60},
      {"date": "2023-01-07", "total": 50}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "isValid(datum.date)"},
    {
      "window": [{"op": "sum", "field": "total", "as": "cumulative_total"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "date", "order": "ascending"}],
      "frame": [null, 0]
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "circle",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal", "title": null},
        "y": {
          "field": "cumulative_total",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Cumulative Total"
        },
        "tooltip": {"field": "cumulative_total", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "blue"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal", "title": null},
        "y": {
          "field": "cumulative_total",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Cumulative Total"
        },
        "tooltip": {"field": "cumulative_total", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "blue"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "circle",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal", "title": null},
        "y": {"field": "total", "type": "quantitative", "title": "total"},
        "tooltip": {"field": "total", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "red"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal", "title": null},
        "y": {"field": "total", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Total"},
        "tooltip": {"field": "total", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "red"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```

Adam

Comment: Thanks for the example; I think what I am trying to do is not possible as I want to calculate cumulative totals for three different datasets which have varying levels of 'completeness' .. (Baseline dates, Planned dates and actual dates)  ; it doesn't seem possible to filter each dataset separately for a valid date and then plot them each in the same chart. I ended up 'fixing' the null fields with an additional formulae fields in the base data.

Comment: You should consider adding a Calendar date table/view and connecting your data to this on the date column. So you will get a date for every day with or without data. Feel free to mark this as completed since my answer did answer your question (kind of) :)